# How can I map values of an array into command objects using Grails?

Tags: grails, mapping, command-objects

normally I use command objects to work with submitted values. But if multiple values of the same property are submitted via AJAX (using jQuery) I was not able to use command objects.

In my GUI the user can click on checkboxes to mark some objects. Let's assume the name of the checkboxes is provider, i.e.

```
<input type=checkbox name=provider value=1>
<input type=checkbox name=provider value=2>
and so on...
```

When the clicked values are submitted via AJAX, in the Grails controller these values are in an map:

```
params.'provider[]'
```

where the key is provider[] and the value is an array of Strings if multiple checkboxes are clicked, otherwise it's just a String.

The problem is, that I can not create a command object with a property named provider[]. What I tried was:

```
class MyCommand {
    Long[] provider
    // or
    List<Long> provider
}
```

but that didn't work.

So, my question is, how can I use a command object in this case? I want Grails to do the mapping, I do not want to do the mapping myself.

I am using Grails 2.3.11.

Thanks in advance,
best regards,

Daniel

Answer (score 0):

To use command object, change your check box name to provider[index]

```
<input type="checkbox" name="provider[0]" value=1>
<input type="checkbox" name="provider[1]" value=2>
and so on...
```

and change your command object --

```
import org.apache.commons.collections.FactoryUtils
import org.apache.commons.collections.ListUtils

class MyCommand {
    List<Provider> provider = ListUtils.lazyList([], FactoryUtils.instantiateFactory(Provider))
}
```

Comment: This won't work, because I am submitting these values with jQuery and the name of the property is fix: jQuery.ajax( {url: ..., data: {provider: collectedValues} });

Comment: OK. You can also send params using `serialize` method of jQuery, and in this case you can use above approach. Place your inputs (check-boxes) in a div and gives this div a class or id, eg. class `textAjaxClass`. Then send params in ajax like -- `data: $('.textAjaxClass :input').serialize(),`

Comment: Thanks, you are right. This would solve the issue. The problem is that the jQuery AJAX call is jQuery.ajax { ... data: { provider: providerArray } } This will result in the property named provider[] on the server side. The thing is that I can not change the Javascript code, because it´s a legacy systems I´ve to use.